# Mono-based Replacement for Microsoft.VisualBasic ComputerInfo

Tags: c#, mono

I have following c# code running perfectly fine in visual studio but if want to compile it on mono it simply fails with error CmputerInfo doesn't exists are you missing assembly reference.

```
// Get Total Available Memory Percentage and if its below a threshhold then send ServiceUnavailable
            ComputerInfo computerInfo = new ComputerInfo();
            ulong totalPhysicalMemory = computerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory;
            ulong availablePhysicalMemory = computerInfo.AvailablePhysicalMemory;
            ulong availablePhysicalMemoryPercentage = (availablePhysicalMemory * 100 / totalPhysicalMemory);
```

If the above dll doesn't supported by mono. Please tell me how to gather above information in linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a replacement:

```
var pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Mono Memory", "Available Physical Memory");
long availableMemory = pc.RawValue;
var pc2 = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Mono Memory", "Total Physical Memory");
long physicalMemory = pc2.RawValue;
```

Comment: @SushilHangover Thanks